# Popup text window works in Windows, not on Mac

Tags: python, popupwindow, onmouseover

I'm trying to write an app that works in both Windows and MacOS environments with minimal code differences.

The following code works great in Windows. It gives me a text window on mouseover of a button and it goes away upon exit of the button:

```
class ToolTip(object):

    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tipwindow = None
        self.id = None
        self.x = self.y = 0

    def showtip(self, text):
        """Display text in tooltip window"""
        self.text = text
        if self.tipwindow or not self.text:
            return
        x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox("insert") ## The offending line
        x = x + self.widget.winfo_rootx() + 57
        y = y + cy + self.widget.winfo_rooty() + 35
        self.tipwindow = tw = Toplevel(self.widget)
        tw.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        label = Label(tw, text=self.text, justify=LEFT,
                      background="#ffffe0", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1,
                      font=("tahoma", "8", "normal"))
        label.pack(ipadx=1)

    def hidetip(self):
        tw = self.tipwindow
        self.tipwindow = None
        if tw:
            tw.destroy()


def CreateToolTip(widget, text):
    toolTip = ToolTip(widget)

    def enter(event):
        toolTip.showtip(text)

    def leave(event):
        toolTip.hidetip()

    widget.bind('<Enter>', enter)
    widget.bind('<Leave>', leave)
```

When I try to run this in a MacOS environment, I get the following:

```
    x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox("insert")
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I am totally lost. Please help.

Comment: What versions of Python are you using on the two platforms?

Comment: 3.9 on the Mac, 3.8 on Windows